# Вырезать текст между тегами регуляркой

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо выдрать текст к примеру между тегами с помощью регулярных выражений.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = @"bla bla bla blablaa <title>TITLE</title> bla bla bla bla";

        string match = Regex.Match(text, @"<title>(.*)</title>").ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(match);
    }
```

В нескольких местах в нете нашел, что именно такой паттерн должен выдрать текст между тегами, но на практике в строке **match** оказывается значение **`"<title>TITLE</title>"`**, а мне нужно, чтобы там было только **"TITLE"**. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Вы случайно не собираетесь парсить HTML регулярными выражениями? Подумайте о том, что может быть в комментарии.

Comment: Ну теги это я как пример привел просто. 
А вообще, если скажем нужно спарсить просто тот же тайтл, то зачем для такого простого действия подключать еще какие-то сторонние библиотеки типа HtmlAgilityPack, ведь в дотнете на сколько мне известно нет встроенных средств для парсинга HTML. Еще можно в принципе сделать метод для выдергивания текста из тегов с помощью встроенных методов string.StartsWith, string.EndsWith и т. д. Но это получится строк 8 кода против одной строки регуляркой. Да и думается мне, что регулярки побыстрее будут работать, или нет? 
Я нуб, так что критика приветствуется )

Comment: @junior_dev: давайте я повторюсь. Внутри HTML-файла позволяются комментарии. Ответьте себе на вопрос: что может быть в комментарии? Если ответ "например, любой HTML-тег", вы на правильном пути.

Comment: @junior_dev: регулярки будут работать не быстрее, чем ручной парсинг. Но зато они проще. И при ручном парсинге вы судя по всему собираетесь сделать точно такую же ошибку.

Comment: @VladD Понятно, значит нужно первым делом удалить все комментарии из HTML строки, если они есть. Сделать это проще всего теми же регулярками, верно? А потом уже со строкой, очищенной от комментариев, делать что угодно. 
И еще, перед тем как работать со строкой, нужно удостовериться, что там кодировка UTF-8, а то на некоторых сайтах еще может быть windows-1251, нужно перекодировать, иначе регулярки нормально не будут работать.

Comment: @junior_dev: Не-а, этого недостаточно. Кроме комментариев (которые ещё надо уметь выкусить) есть [блоки CDATA и различные варианты расстановки пробелов](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7078850/276994). Есть ещё [entities](http://stackoverflow.com/a/702222/276994). Ещё строки внутри скриптов. Вы и правда собираетесь обойти все эти препятствия? Если да, мои поздравления, вы собираетесь написать ещё одну библиотеку для парсинга HTML. Может, лучше взять готовую?

Comment: @VladD Ясно, спасибо за разъяснение.
Кстати, а вы не могли бы посоветовать какой-нить парсер, кроме HtmlAgilityPack? Нет, он очень даже ок, но хотелось бы и другие посмотреть, а все только про него и пишут. Неужели альтернатив нет?

Comment: (Это не ответ, но комментарии сверху закончились, так что продолжаю тут.)

Я другого парсера не знаю, сорри, посоветовать не могу. Но на StackOverflow [предлагают](http://stackoverflow.com/q/56107/276994) и другие варианты:

 * [HtmlDocument.LoadHtml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8061141/276994)
 * [mshtml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56228/276994)
 * [WebBrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56629/276994)
 * [Majestic-12](http://stackoverflow.com/a/100423/276994)

Хотя HtmlAgilityPack, конечно, в лидерах.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нужно исключить из результата теги (`Positive lookbehind/lookahead`):

```
(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно )

Answer (score 1):

Вообще проблема в твоём коде была из-за того что `Regex.Match` возвращает совпадение с шаблоном регулярного выражения, тоесть с `"<title>(.*)</title>"`, часть регулярного выражения `"(.*)"` называется "группой". Поэтому у класса `Match` есть свойство `Groups`, из которого по индексу группы или по её имени (имя задаётся к примеру так: `(?<title>.*)` можно выковырять нужную группу.

А вообще за парсинг XHTML'а регулярками действительно нужно бить по-рукам.