# Regex C# как ограничить захват?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача выбирать значения только корректных тегов. Я приведу пример

```
List<string> res = new List<string>();
string input = "<p>vasya<p>lena</p><p>gena</p>";
string pattern = "<p>(.*?)</p>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    res.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Заметьте довольно простое рег. выражение, но к сожалению оно выдает

```
res[0] "vasya<p>lena"
res[1] "gena"
```

а должно взять только **lena** и **gena**.

Хотелось бы решить не только этот конкретный пример, а научиться универсально ограничивать регулярку последним началом до (.*?) к первому концу

Comment: Если это HTML, то и используйте правильный инструментарий!

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk, в вопросе как раз и спрашивается, как поменять регулярку, чтобы результат был такой, как требуется :)

Comment: _Есть задача выбирать значения только корректных тегов._ - в соответствии со [спецификацией](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#optional-start-and-end-tags) в примере все теги корректные

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вырезать текст между тегами регуляркой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189364/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: Просто примените к результату еще одну регулярку, наподобие `(?:.*<p>)*(.+)`

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk, я не понял твой комментарий :) вопрос был: _должно взять только lena и gena потому что эти теги имеют целостность. **подскажите что дописать в регулярку?**_ И это было в начальной редакции вопроса.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk, редакции вопроса можно посмотреть по ссылке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1109208/revisions

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо